# Using LINQ Query

Tags: asp.net, linq

I have a linq query.

```
var query = (from s in dc.ClassInfos
                 where s.ClassName == tbSubject.Text
                 select new{
                  location = s.ClassLocation,
                  Date = s.ClassDate
                 });
```

Now I like to assign the location value to a local variable. Can you help me how to do this?

Comment: Which location? You could have multiple results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you query returns an `IEnumerable` of an anonymous class - not just a single value. If you wanted to assign the *first* location value (provided there is one) you could do:

```
var location =  query.First().location;
```

If you want all locations in a list on the other hand this should work:

```
var locations =  query.Select( x=> x.location).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var location = query.First().location;
```

But I would write

```
var location = (from s in dc.ClassInfos
                where s.ClassName == tbSubject.Text
                select s.ClassLocation).FirstOrDefault();
```

because you don't need to select `Date` if you only use `location`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var localVar = new List<string>();  

foreach (var item in query)
{
  localvars.add(item.location);
}
```

Comment: There are much more elegant ways of doing this. Also, I don't think this answers OPs question.